# Beanstalk single instance & NodeJS - https won't work

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Followed all the steps at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-nodejs.html , with self-signed certificate info for server.crt and server.key.

Everything works fine on http. But when I go to the https version of the URL, it tells me "beanstalkurl.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com refused to connect."

I checked the security group of the beanstalk deployment and it has 443 inbound so it appears that https-instance-single.config file was successful at least... I don't see any errors in my Beanstalk logs.

Any thoughts on how to resolve? Really don't wanna pay 200/year for a load balancer, especially if they say this should work as well.

Comment: How exactly did you setup your ssl? For this you need your own domain, not `beanstalkurl.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`.

Comment: I used my domain (example.com, so without the www) for signing the certificate. Then put the Route 53 domani (example.com, so without the www) to redirect to the Beanstalk environment

Answer (score 0):

It feels like I've tried everything.

- Use the Beanstalk domain for the self signed certificate
- Use 'localhost' for the self-signed certificate
- Use the domain I purchased for the self-signed certificate, and in Route53 link it to the Beanstalk environment

All using the two files and .ebextensions folder mentioned in: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-nodejs.html

Maybe they just want you to pay for a load balancer after all :-)

Error log is empty:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to achieve the same thing, but I had a Java app instead of Node.js. My subdomain was resolving correctly to the ELB URL, but using HTTPS caused the connection to be refused.

My own problem was with `server_name localhost;` in NGINX conf file. Once I replaced `localhost` with my `sub.domain.com` for which I generated my certificate, the HTTPS traffic started to flow.